# Two different answers by applying AM GM Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, inequality, arithmetic-progressions

Find minimum value of $f(x)=\sec^2 x+\csc ^2x$

We have $$f(x)=2+\tan^2 x+\cot ^2 x$$

Method $1.$ we have $$\frac{\tan^2 x+\cot^2 x}{2} \ge 1$$  $\implies$

$$f(x) \ge 4$$

Method $2.$

We have $$\frac{2+\tan^2 x+\cot^2 x}{3} \ge 2^{\frac{1}{3}}$$  $\implies$

$$f(x) \ge 3(2^{\frac{1}{3}})-2$$

But whats wrong in method $2$?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, your inequality (2) is valid. It does not give you the minimum, because there equality is never possible, so it remains a lower bound. Note $4> 3(2^{1/3})-2$.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AM=GM** holds only in case all terms are equals but $\tan x=\cot x=2$ is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

The second equality is untenable as $\tan x=\cot x\implies\tan x=?$

Answer (score 0):

Because in your second AM-GM the equality should be occur for $2=\tan^2x=\cot^2x,$ which is impossible.

The right way is the following.

By AM-GM
$$f(x)\geq2+2\sqrt{\tan^2x\cot^2x}=2+2=4.$$
The equality occurs for $x=45^{\circ},$ which says that $4$ is a minimal value.